# ARM-SVE: wrapping runtime sized register

Tags: gcc, armv8, sve

In a generic SIMD library [eve](https://github.com/jfalcou/eve) we were looking into supporting length agnostic `sve`

However, we cannot wrap a `sizeless` register into a struct to do some meta-programming around it.

```
struct foo {
  svint8_t a;
};
```

Is there a way to do it? Either clang or gcc.

I found some talk of `__sizeless_struct` and some patches flying around but I think it didn't go anywhere.
I also found these [gcc tests](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/aarch64/sve/acle/general-c/sizeless-2.c#L1) - no wrapping of a register in a struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately this isn't possible (at the time of writing).  `__sizeless_struct` was an experimental feature that Arm added as part of the initial downstream implementation of the SVE ACLE in Clang.  The main purpose was to allow tuple types like `svfloat32x3_t` to be defined directly in `<arm_sve.h>`.  But the feature had complex, counter-trend semantics.  It broke one of the fundamental rules of C++, which is that all class objects have a constant size, so it would have been an ongoing maintenance burden for upstream compilers.

`__sizeless_struct` (or something like it) probably wouldn't be acceptable for a portable SIMD framework, since the sizeless struct would inherit all of the restrictions of sizeless vector types: no global variables, no uses in normal structs, etc.  Either all SIMD targets would have to live by those restrictions, or the restrictions would vary by target (limiting portability).

Function-based abstraction might be a better starting point than class-based abstraction for SIMD frameworks that want to support variable-length vectors.  [Google Highway](https://github.com/google/highway) is an example of this and it works well for SVE.

Comment: I appreciate you replying. Unfortunately this makes a lot of what we want to do almost impossible - like processing parallel arrays in a generic way. Hopefully, this will be revisited at some point.